# How do I put 1 number into pastebin, print it out and wait 1 second and than put the second number

Tags: python, selenium, variables, automation

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:\\Users\\Abdul_szuzdge\\Downloads\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe")

Numbers = ['10','20','30','40']

driver.get('https://pastebin.com')
Paste = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="postform-text"]')
Paste.click()

Paste.send_keys(Numbers)
print(Numbers)
time.sleep(1)
```

basically what I want to do is put 1 number into Pastebin paste than wait 1 second and then put the second number, I want to get the numbers from The 'Numbers' variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep

driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:\\Users\\Abdul_szuzdge\\Downloads\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe")

Numbers = ['10', '20', '30', '40']

driver.get('https://pastebin.com')

Paste = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="postform-text"]')
Paste.click()

for Number in Numbers:
    Paste.send_keys(Number)
    print(Number)
    sleep(1)
```

Using "for item in items" is very useful in using lists. it calls the elements in the list one by one and runs the length of the list.

If you use "from time import sleep" instead of "import time" when using sleep, you will use less memory.

I hope I helped. You can ask if you get stuck